# Image not display in android device but display in android emulator React-Native

Tags: react-native

I store image in s3. Before Storing image in s3, I concatinate the 64 size string with it. 
we get the image url its not display the image in android mobile but if I paste the url in brower it give the image. 
If use other image from internet that is working fine but our s3 image is not display.
I run the app in android emulator it display the image.

Comment: Please can you try setting `android:largeHeap="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml (under `application`).

Comment: I tried it but not working.

Answer (score 0):

tried adding the resizeMethod="resize" prop?

Comment: Please rephrase this to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question, which of course you should do by using your commenting privilege. If you consider this an answer then please add some explanation.